# Intuit API request failing with generic error when connecting to Desktop, but works for Online

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Using the IPP.NET SDK v2.0.1, having an issue where simple requests are failing with generic error messages specifically when connecting to a QuickBooks Desktop instance.

Online works fine.

**Connection Method:**

```
    public QBClient(string appToken, string companyId, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, ServiceType qbService)
    {
        AppToken = appToken;
        CompanyID = companyId;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
        AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret;
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;

        IntuitServicesType ist = IntuitServicesType.QBO;

        if (qbService == ServiceType.QBDesktop)
        {
            ist = IntuitServicesType.QBD;
        }

        _oAuthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
        _serviceContext = new ServiceContext(AppToken, CompanyID, ist, _oAuthValidator);

        string ticket = _serviceContext.Ticket;
        this.DataService = new Intuit.Ipp.DataService.DataService(_serviceContext);
    }
```

The connection method above throws no exceptions. However, the following call:

`DataService.FindAll<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer>(customer, 1, 1000);`

produces the following request / response captured in Fiddler:

**Request:**

URL: `POST https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/COMPANY-ID-REMOVED/query`

Body: `select * from Customer startPosition 1 maxResults 1000`

**Response:**

`{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Operation failed, see details for error","code":"1000"}],"type":"Validation"},"time":"2013-11-16T00:20:30.739Z"}`

What should be changed to successfully query QuickBooks Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V3 QBD can return at max 500 results in a time unlike V3 QBO which can return 1000. Please alter your query. We have an enhancement request up for this.